# Streaming file from Dropbox to a User's Browser

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

The following code is from the Dropbox API to download the file from a user's dropbox account to the webserver making the API request.

```
$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

However, Instead of downloading the file to the web server, I would like to send the file to the user (stream the file byte-by-byte). Is this possible ?

Comment: The web server is your server?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Dropbox API offers a "media" call that returns a direct link to a file that you can pass to the client for use (e.g., to stream locally):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media

This corresponds to the "createTemporaryDirectLink" method in the PHP SDK:

http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.0.x/source-class-Dropbox.Client.html#948-977

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen("php://output", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
header($fileMetadata['mime_type']);
fclose($f);
```